# Convert datetime to ISO 8601 format

Tags: xslt

I have the following element which holds a datetime value.

I am trying to convert it to `ISO 8601` UTC, basically, I am trying to do the following:

**input:**

```
"lastUpdatedAt": "2019-07-21T13:47:44.000+0100"
```

**desired output:**

```
"lastUpdatedAt": "2019-07-21T12:47:44.000Z"
```

**What I have tried so far:**

```
  <xsl:template match="map/string[@key='lastUpdatedAt']">
    <xsl:variable name="lastUpdatedAt" select="."/>
      <string key="lastUpdatedAt">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space($lastUpdatedAt),
          '^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s+(.*)','$3-$1-$2T$4Z')"/>
      </string>
  </xsl:template>
```

**The output I get:**

```
"lastUpdatedAt": "2019-07-21T13:47:44.000+0100"
```

Comment: What version of xsl can you use? 2.0 has the function "adjust-dateTime-to-timezone" available.

Comment: The input you show is already in YYYY-MM-DD format, so your regex does not make sense. Note however, that the timezone is missing a `:` separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input is actually:

```
"lastUpdatedAt": "07-21-2019 13:47:44.000+0100"
```

you can convert it to an ISO-8601 dateTime in the UTC timezone by doing:

```
<xsl:template match="string[@key='lastUpdatedAt']">
    <xsl:variable name="iso-dateTime" select="replace(. ,'^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s+(.*)([+-])(\d{2})(\d{2})','$3-$1-$2T$4$5$6:$7')" />
    <string key="lastUpdatedAt">
         <xsl:value-of select="adjust-dateTime-to-timezone(xs:dateTime($iso-dateTime), xs:dayTimeDuration('PT0H'))"/>
    </string>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqm/2

Comment: Thank you! This looks like what I need, but when I add it in my code I get the following error: ````Invalid dateTime value "2019-07-21T13:47:44.000+0100" (Timezone hour must be two digits)````

Comment: Then you are not adding "it" to your code. My `replace()` adds a `:` separator to the timezone. Your error message shows a string without such separator (as I also mentioned in a comment to your question). Or perhaps your input is different from what I guessed.

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that in my code I also have datetime elements with the following format ````2016-06-18T10:40:58.000+0100````, that's why it was failing.

Comment: Is your question answered then/

Comment: Yes, thank you, I guess it's my fault for not realizing earlier that I might have also this type of input, for which I need to find a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is expecting white space `\s` after `^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})`

change this to `T` from your input date.

```
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space($lastUpdatedAt),
          '^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T+(.*)','$1-$2-$3T$4Z')"/>
```